# Updated to Free JQGrid 4.13 from 4.4 javascript onclick on action item not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

I had someone code this App about 6 years ago and I am trying to update the JQGrid to use its new features.  I am having 2 issues.  The buttons at the top not longer appear and the inline button onlick items no longer work.  I do not know if the original code is well done or not and javascript is not a strength of mine so I would appreciate any help.  Here is the code:

```
function document_list(document_file_path, root_path, row_num, row_list, param)
{
    var page_path = root_path + '/modules/documents/document_list_process.php';

    /*Seup config of JqGrid for Staff List page*/
    jQuery('#document_list').jqGrid({
        url: page_path,
        datatype: 'json',
        mtype: 'POST',
        loadui: 'block', //Blocks all actions in the grid until the ajax request is finished
        colNames:['Document Id','User Id', 'File Name', 'Shared By', '', 'Title', 'File Size','Type','Date Created','Share Level','Count','Action'],
        colModel:[
            {name: 'document_id', index: 'document_id',
                hidden: true,
                title: false},
            {name: 'user_id', index: 'user_id',
                hidden: true,
                title: false},
            {name: 'file_name', index: 'file_name',
                hidden: true,
                title: false},
            {name: 'first_name', index: 'first_name',
                hidden: true,
                title: false},
            {name: 'image', index: 'image', width: 7, align: 'center',
                editable: false,
                search: false,
                resizable: false,
                title: false},
            {name: 'title', index: 'title', width:18, align: 'left',
                editable: false,
                resizable: true,
                title: false},
            {name: 'file_size', index: 'file_size', width: 13, align: 'center',
                editable: false,
                resizable: true,
                title: false},
            {name: 'file_ext', index: 'file_ext', width: 5, align: 'center',
                editable: false,
                resizable: true,
                title: false,
                stype: 'select',
                editoptions:
                {
                    value:
                    {
                        'pdf':'pdf',
                        'xls':'xls',
                        'doc':'doc',
                        'odt':'odt',
                        'ods':'ods',
                        'ppt':'ppt',
                        'odp':'odp',
                        'xml':'xml',
                        'htm':'htm',
                        'html':'html',
                        'txt':'txt',
                        'sql':'sql',
                        'csv':'csv'
                    }
                }},
            {name: 'created_on', index:'created_on', width: 12, align: 'center',
                editable: false,
                resizable: false,
                search: false,
                title: false},
            {name: 'sl.share_level_id', index:'sl.share_level_id', width: 12, align: 'center',
                editable: false,
                resizable: false,
                stype: 'select',
                editoptions: {
                    value: {
                        3: 'All Associates',
                        2: 'Company Only',
                        1: 'Private',
                        4: 'Public',
                        8: 'Specific Associate',
                        9: 'Specific Group'
                    }
                },
                title: false},
            {name: 'access_count', index: 'access_count', width: 11, align: 'center',
                editable: false,
                resizable: true,
                title: false},              
            {name: 'action', width: 10, align: 'center',
                editable: false,
                resizable: true,
                sortable: false,
                search: false,
                viewable: false,
                title: false}                 
        ],
        rowNum: row_num, //Default number of row for each page
        rowList: row_list, //List of rows available as drop down
        pager: '#page_document_list', //Div ID of the pager set in HTMl page
        sortname: 'file_name', //Default sorting order based on first name
        viewrecords: true,
        rownumbers: false, //Display row number
        resizable: false, //Resizable option for Grid
        sortorder: 'asc',
        caption: false, //Caption of Grid
        height: 'auto', //Height of Grid
        width: $(window).width()*(0.9), //Width of Grid
        hidegrid: false, //Option for show/Hide of Grid
        toolbar: [true,'bottom'], //Display toolbar at the top
        multiselect: true, //Display check box for multiple selection
        toppager: true, //Display pagination at top along with the bottom one
        footerrow : true,
        userDataOnFooter : true,

        /*Insert required button to the 'Action' column for Edit operation*/
        gridComplete: function(){
            var ids = jQuery('#document_list').jqGrid('getDataIDs');

            for(var i = 0; i < ids.length ; i++)
            {
                var cl = ids[i];
                var document_id = $('#document_list').getCell(cl, 'document_id');
                var file_ext = $('#document_list').getCell(cl, 'file_ext');
                var user_id = $('#document_list').getCell(cl, 'user_id');
                var title = $('#document_list').getCell(cl, 'title');
                var file_name = $('#document_list').getCell(cl, 'file_name') +'.' + file_ext;
                var process_path = root_path + '/modules/documents/document_process.php';

                edit_btn = '<a onclick=\'getDetail("' + cl + '", "edit", "' + root_path + '", "' + document_file_path + '");\' ' +
                    'id="note_edit">Edit</a><span style="color: gray;">';
                btn_sep = '&nbsp;|&nbsp;<span>'; //Button separator
                view_btn = '<a onclick=\'getDetail("' + cl + '", "view", "' + root_path + '", "' + document_file_path + '");\' ' +
                    'id="note_view">View</a>';

                if(file_ext == 'pdf')
                {
                    open_btn = '<a onclick=\'getDetail("' + cl + '", "open", "' + root_path + '", "' + document_file_path + '");\' ' +
                        'id="document_open">Open</a><span style="color: gray;">';
                }
                else
                {                   
                    open_btn = '<a onclick="calculateAccessCount(\'' + root_path + '\', ' + document_id + ')" href="' + document_file_path + user_id +'/' + file_name + '" ' +
                        ' class="download" title="' + title + '" id="' + encodeURIComponent(document_file_path + user_id +'/' + file_name )+ '">Open</a><span style="color: gray;">';
                }

                jQuery('#document_list').jqGrid('setRowData', ids[i],{action: edit_btn + btn_sep + open_btn});
            }


        /*Down load attached file*/ 
        $('a.download').jDownload({
            root: root_path + '/libraries/', //Set the root path for plug-in
            dialogTitle: 'File Download' //Set title for the download pop-up
        });
        } 
    });

    /*Set navigation setup used for pagination*/
    setNavigation('document_list', false, false, false, false, false, false, false); //Bottom Navigation bar
    setNavigation('document_list', false, false, false, false, false, true, false); //Top Navigation bar    

    /*Label alignment for Your available company area*/
    jQuery('#document_list').jqGrid('setLabel', 'image', '', {'text-align':'left'});
    jQuery('#document_list').jqGrid('setLabel', 'title', 'Title', {'text-align':'left'});
    jQuery('#document_list').jqGrid('setLabel', 'file_size', 'File Size', {'text-align':'center'});
    jQuery('#document_list').jqGrid('setLabel', 'access_count', 'Views', {'text-align':'center'});
    jQuery('#document_list').jqGrid('setLabel', 'file_ext', 'Type', {'text-align':'center'});
    jQuery('#document_list').jqGrid('setLabel', 'created_on', 'Date Created', {'text-align':'center'});
    jQuery('#document_list').jqGrid('setLabel', 'sl.share_level_id', 'Share Level', {'text-align':'center'});
    jQuery('#document_list').jqGrid('setLabel', 'action', 'Action', {'text-align':'center'});

    addToolBarButton('document_list', 'delete_document', 1, 'Delete');

}
```

I would appreciate any feedback and assistance.  I have tried going through the existing help and information and make small changes but I cannot make it work.

Thank you,

Jim

Comment: You wrote "The buttons at the top not longer appear and the inline button onlick items no longer work.", but you add the top buttons with respect of unknown `setNavigation` and `calculateAccessCount`, `getDetail` etc are undefined foo. By the way the inline buttons have clear bugs: you use **the same** `id` values for all buttons (see `document_open`, `note_view`). It's unclear which version of jQuery, jQuery UI, jDownload you use and the format of data returned from `url: page_path`. If would be helpful if you create the demo (in JSFiddle, for exampl), which reproduces the problem.

Comment: Thank you for this - I am working on trying to setup in JSFiddle.  It has lots of modules that link ... will post when done.

Comment: While going through all the code to set this up in JSFiddle, I found the issues and have this fixed.  Thank you!